# React Native Chat App, Flatlist useRef is null

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, chat, react-native-flatlist

Im building a chat app with React Native using Expo and I use a Flatlist as child of KeyboardAvoidingView to render the list of messages, the problem is I want to scroll to the bottom when the keyboard is triggered

So I used the Flatlist method ( scrollToEnd ) with useRef hook and my code looks like this :

```
const ChatBody = ({ messages }) => {

      const listRef = useRef(null);

      useEffect(() => {
        Keyboard.addListener("keyboardWillShow", () => {
          setTimeout(() => listRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true }), 100);
        });

        return () => Keyboard.removeListener("keyboardWillShow");
      }, []);

      return (
        <FlatList
          ref={listRef}
          keyboardDismissMode="on-drag"
          data={messages}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id || String(Math.random())}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Message {...item} />}
       />
}
```

The code works just fine at the first render, but when I leave the screen and get back again and trigger the keyboard I get this error :

```
TypeError : null in not an object (evaluating 'listRef.current.scrollToEnd')
```

*The reason I added setTimout was because the scrollToEnd for some reason does not work when the keyboard event is triggered. adding setTimeout solved that issue.

The component tree is kinda like this :

StackNavigatorScreen => KeyboardAvoidingView => FlatList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your event handler as a second parameter to `Keyboard.removeListener`. Since you're only passing in the first argument, your handler is run anyway and before your ref could be set.

```js
const ChatBody = ({ messages }) => {
    const listRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        Keyboard.addListener("keyboardWillShow", onKeyboardWillShow);

        return () => Keyboard.removeListener("keyboardWillShow", onKeyboardWillShow);
    }, []);

    function onKeyboardWillShow() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            listRef.current.scrollToEnd();
        }, 100);
    }

    return (
        <FlatList
            ref={listRef}
            keyboardDismissMode="on-drag"
            data={messages}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id || String(Math.random())}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Message {...item} />}
        />
    )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`const listRef = useRef(null);` <-- this line is the one causing the problem.

You need to assign an object, `null` in this case cannot be put there as it is not an object.

Comment: This is not true at all. `useRef` takes an initial value and is set later on during rendering via the `ref`prop which OP is using.